# JSONDecodeError skip

Tags: python, json, dataframe, error-handling

I am trying to get a new column in a dataframe with the function passed in it and this is a working code. (The function is an API scrape and idk how to 1) edit it or 2) trouble shoot it)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = myarray)
df.columns=["A"]
df['B']= 'US'

array_thing=[]

for i in range(len(df)):
    array_thing.append(mycoolfunction(df.iloc[i, 0], df.iloc[i, 1]))
df['new']=array_thing

df
```

Now I need to skip the error that is raised in some lines saying:
**JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**

Ive already tried looking at other stackoverflows and every possible 'try''continue' codes, im so confused about what to do.

I have tried the following:

```
try:
    for i in range(len(df)):
        array_thing.append(mycoolfunction(df.iloc[i, 0], df.iloc[i, 1]))
        df['new']=array_thing
    except JSONDecodeError as e:
        continue
```

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    try:
        array_thing.append(mycoolfunction(df.iloc[i, 0], df.iloc[i, 1]))
        df['new']=array_thing
    except <JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)> as e:
        print('error!')
df
```

none of it works.. I just need it to skip over the error and either not produce anything in that row or just say error and continue.

something like this in a dataframe:
| a| b| jsoncode|
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| A123| US    | Error|

and then just continue showing the json for all those that work.

thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to treat diferent errors, try just:

```
import traceback

for i in range(len(df)):
    try:
        array_thing.append(mycoolfunction(df.iloc[i, 0], df.iloc[i, 1]))
        df['new']=array_thing
    except Exception as e:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        print("your traceback", e)
```

Or if you just want to ignore any errors, just:

```
...   
except:
        pass
```

Comment: I just tried that, it says except as e: has a syntax error

Comment: and "except: pass" ?

Comment: or also "except Exception as e:" - i have edited the answer

Comment: So it ran without stopping for errors but it didnt product the 3rd column with all the json values like it was before...